# How can I dynamically invoke all instance methods starting with a given prefix?

Tags: php, oop, dynamic

i have a class and i want to call dynamicly all functions starting by default name:

```
class social_button
{
     public function __construct()
     {
         [...]
     }

     private function social_facebook()
     {[...]}

     private function social_instagramm();
     {[...]}

     private function social_twitter();
     {[...]}

     [and so on]
}
```

My matter is, that i wont write all time:

```
$this->social_facebook();
$this->social_twitter();
...
```

because it could/will be an endless list.

So here is my questions:

Is there a way to call all functions generic/dynamic starting with "social"?
Like: `$this->social_*()`;

(The " * " is something like a placeholder, which contains an unlimited number of chars)

Sorry for my bad english and much thanks to all answers.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: See [the answer by localheinz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45649876/4458445) below for a better method, using reflection. `get_class_methods()` will only return public methods.

---

Building off **hsz**'s answer:

You can get the list of a class' methods using [`get_class_methods()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php). Then you can loop through the results, and call the method if it starts with "social_".

```
// Get the list of methods
$class_methods = get_class_methods("social_button");

// Loop through the list of method names
foreach ($class_methods as $method_name)
{
    // Are the first 7 characters "social_"?
    if (substr($method_name, 0, 7) == "social_")
    {
        // Call the method
        $this->{$method_name}();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exact, what i'm searching for.

Comment: Thanks to ALL answers

Comment: Please change `substring` to `substr`. It will cause runtime errors. Just a little hint, that others wont to the same fault as i did

Comment: `get_class_methods()` returns `public` methods only, but the methods are declared as `private`, see https://3v4l.org/PVqgD.

Comment: @localheinz Excellent point. I didn't pay attention to the scope of the methods in the OP's question. I've updated my answer to direct to yours.

Comment: @RobbieToyota Ha, no worries!

Answer (score 4):

You can build the method name with the string concatenation:

```
$service = 'facebook';
$this->{'social_' . $service}();
```

or

```
$service = 'social_facebook';
$this->$service();
```

If you wan to call all of them, go with:

```
$services = ['facebook', 'twitter'];
foreach ($services as $service) {
  $this->{'social_' . $service}();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i dont think, thats what i want. I want a method/solution to call all functions starting with `social`. However, this is a nice solution.

Comment: You can create a property with an array of available services and call them within a loop.

Comment: Something like: `$this->{'social_' . ' ' };`

Comment: So I have to write all social services (like Facebook, Twitter, Instagramm and a lot more) in an array? Thats even the same and not that performant

Comment: @SacrumDeus Another possibility is to use Reflections to find out all class methods, but it can be expensive.

Comment: How would it look like?

Comment: Make service an array, loop through the array calling social_ . $service[i] to do what you require. Just have all end words of your social functions defined within the array. Assuming none of them have parameters/unique parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the accepted answer is that it will not work with the example posted with the question. `get_class_methods()` returns only `public` methods, but the methods in question are marked as `private`.

If you want to determine all methods, use reflection instead:

```
class social_button
{
    private function social_facebook()
    {
        return 'Facebook';
    }

    private function social_instagram()
    {
        return 'Instagram';
    }

    private function social_twitter()
    {
        return 'Twitter';
    }

    public function all()
    {
        $reflection = new \ReflectionObject($this);

        $prefix = 'social_';

        // filter out methods which do not start with the given prefix
        $methods = array_filter($reflection->getMethods(), function (\ReflectionMethod $method) use ($prefix) {
            return 0 === strpos($method->getName(), $prefix);
        });

        // invoke all methods and collect the results in an array
        $results = array_map(function (\ReflectionMethod $method) {
            $name = $method->getName();

            return $this->$name();
        }, $methods);

        return $results;
    }
}

$button = new social_button();

var_dump($button->all());
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionobject.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

For an example, see:

- https://3v4l.org/qTkOM